Specify GDAL WarpOption align=False in rasterio function
After many hours of troubleshooting and scouring forums, I was able to solve a problem I was having: after using rasterio to clip one raster to the size of another, the shapes were slightly off so I couldn't do numpy operations (raster files can be downloaded here):
raster1_filepath = 'bps_tile.tif'
r = rasterio.open(raster1_filepath)
r.read(1).shape # returns (4865, 7711)

extent = [-2362425.0,988567.5, -2131113.0,  1134492.0]
bbox = box(extent[0], extent[1], extent[2], extent[3])
geo = bbox.__geo_interface__

raster2_filepath = 'connectivity_compressed.tif'
r2 = rasterio.open(raster2_filepath)
# Crop the raster with the bounding box
out_image, out_transform = rasterio.mask.mask(r2, [geo], crop=True)
np.squeeze(out_image).shape # returns (4865, 7712)

The 7712 vs 7711 is the problem, because I need to do raster1.read(1) - raster2.read(1) and this will throw an error if the shapes aren't exactly the same.
Using the GDAL Warp function, I was able to fix this issue as follows:
def gdal_reproject_helper(src_path, dist_path, dst_crs, bounds, dst_res=(30, 30), interp=0, align=False):
    from osgeo import gdal
    opt = gdal.WarpOptions(dstSRS=dst_crs,
                           outputBounds=bounds,
                           polynomialOrder=interp,
                           targetAlignedPixels=align,
                           xRes=dst_res[0], yRes=dst_res[1])
    gdal.Warp(srcDSOrSrcDSTab=src_path, 
              destNameOrDestDS=dist_path, 
              options=opt)
    return
    
def gdal_reproject(raster1_filepath, raster2_filepath, dest_path):
    import rasterio
    with rasterio.open(raster1_filepath) as tif:
        dst_crs = tif.crs 
        src_bounds = tuple(tif.bounds) # (minX, minY, maxX, maxY)
    
    gdal_reproject_helper(src_path=raster2_filepath, dist_path=dest_path, bounds=src_bounds,
                   dst_crs=dst_crs, dst_res=(30, 30), interp=0, align=False)
    return

gdal_reproject(raster1_filepath, raster2_filepath, 'tmp_tif.tif')
rasterio.open('tmp_tif.tif').read(1).shape # returns (4865, 7711)

The key is the align parameter - when I switch that from False to True, the shape becomes (4866, 7712).
The problem is that running both rasterio and gdal in the same script causes it to crash. As per rasterio's documentation, only one should be run in a script, both will cause problems. I would like to execute the gdal_reproject function above using rasterio, but after reading documentation I haven't seen anything similar to the align parameter. I'm looking for help converting the gdal function to rasterio while getting the correct shape in the output.

Since you already found out that using both GDAL and Rasterio in conjunction isn't possible I'd like to suggest looking into the rasterio Warp module. This is what's behind rasterio reproject.
You might find it easier to switch to rioxarray which is built on rasterio and has a reproject_match function. Good luck!

See https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/blob/main/CHANGES.txt#L1320 and associated doc https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/rasterio.warp.html#rasterio.warp.aligned_target that will make you able to get a result similar to gdal targetAlignedPixels option but in rasterio

Example from https://github.com/rasterio/rasterio/issues/3009 may help too

Thanks for the tips, will do some research!
